# Need help to replace value to zero(enable)

Tags: shell, awk, sed, gawk

I need help to replace an assignment below:

```
  12345678 = {
  CreatedOnToolsVersion = *.*.*;
  DevelopmentTeam = *;
  LastSwiftMigration = *;
  ProvisioningStyle = Manual;
  SystemCapabilities = {
  com.apple.ApplePay = {
  enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.SafariKeychain = {
  enabled = 0; };
  com.apple.SafariKeychain = {
  enabled = 0; 
  };
  };`
  };
  };
```

want the output to contain

```
 com.apple.ApplePay = {
      enabled = 0;
```

I tried with

```
sed '/SystemCapabilites = {\n/ com.apple.ApplePay = {\n/     enabled =0 ;\'
```

outputs

> error:- sed: 1: "/SystemCapabilites = {\ ...": command c expects \
>   followed by text

Comment: `value com.apple.Push` doesn't appear in your input so how can you change it? Clarify and fix that and [edit] your question to show the full desired output given your posted sample input plus what you have tried so far.

Comment: sorry I want to change change com.apple.ApplePay = {
  enabled = 1;

Comment: please fix  your question above and include your best attempt to solve your problem. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Again, include in your question the full expected output given the input you provided. Also format your code just like your formatted your input data so it's legible.

Comment: I presume there are multiple `enabled = 1;` in your file. So a `sed 's/enabled\ =\ 1;/enabled\ =\ 0;/g'` is not applicable for your use case.

Comment: Also please re-format the sed command you have tried already. It is not easy to parse what was the command and what was the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sed to replace multi line strings is [notoriously difficult](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26290/212862)

I can suggest to use perl. This prints out the modified file.

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/com.apple.ApplePay = {\s*\n\s*enabled\ =\ 1;/com.apple.ApplePay = {\nenabled\ =\ 0;/g' file1 2> /dev/null
```

I have not taken into consideration the white spaces in the output. Depending on the indentation of your file you can set spaces before `enabled\ =\ 0`

The input file is called `file1` in my example.

---

Input

```
$ cat file1
12345678 = {
CreatedOnToolsVersion = *.*.*;
DevelopmentTeam = *;
LastSwiftMigration = *;
ProvisioningStyle = Manual;
SystemCapabilities = {
com.apple.ApplePay = {
enabled = 1;
};
com.apple.SafariKeychain = {
enabled = 0; };
com.apple.SafariKeychain = {
enabled = 0;
};
};`
};
};
```

Output

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/com.apple.ApplePay = {\s*\n\s*enabled\ =\ 1;/com.apple.ApplePay = {\nenabled\ =\ 0;/g' file1 2> /dev/null
12345678 = {
CreatedOnToolsVersion = *.*.*;
DevelopmentTeam = *;
LastSwiftMigration = *;
ProvisioningStyle = Manual;
SystemCapabilities = {
com.apple.ApplePay = {
enabled = 0;
};
com.apple.SafariKeychain = {
enabled = 0; };
com.apple.SafariKeychain = {
enabled = 0;
};
};`
};
};
```

---

For in place replacement use

```
 perl -0777 -pi -e 's/com.apple.ApplePay = {\s*\n\s*enabled\ =\ 1;/com.apple.ApplePay = {\nenabled\ =\ 0;/g' file1  2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can see the output in terminal but when I open the file again I see the original value only

Comment: @att I have updated the answer. You need to pass one more parameter to perl for inplace replacement.

Comment: @att  Some best practices to address received answers: If any answer (not necessarily this one) has worked for you, you can think about these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following GNU `sed` command:

```
sed -r '/apple\.ApplePay/,+1s/(enabled =).*/\1 0;/' file
```

Explanation:

`/apple\.ApplePay/,+1` is a range of lines starting with the pattern `apple...` until the next line.

`s/(enabled =).*/\1 0;/'` replaces everything after `enabled =` by itself plus `0;`